# Programmatically localize a String?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization, localizable.strings

Asp.net 4 and C#.

I have a `string` in my Code Behind. I would like assign a value depending on the User's Browser region.

I'm trying with this code, no error, but does not work (no value to a String has been assigned).

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks

```
   string textPrevious = "<%$ Resources:Global, CategoryListSubCategories %>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the solution myself:
Just use `Resources.Global`.

```
string textPrevious = Resources.Global.CategoryListSubCategories;
```

Useful article:
http://shan-tech.blogspot.com/2007/02/aspnet-20-localization-of-string.html

Answer (score 4):

You can do like...

```
string textPrevious = Resources.Global.CategoryListSubCategories;
```

Comment: Thanks I found the same solution

Comment: I was just late in typing and finding the similar thing from one of my project the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an **ExpressionBuilder** to access the code-behind string. The article [.NET String Resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/StringResources.aspx) includes the class **StringExpressionBuilder** with the expression Strings:

```
<asp:Label ID="AppTextLabel" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Strings:MyCompany.MyApp.MyStrings, AppText %>" />
<asp:Label ID="LibTextLabel" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Strings:MyCompany.MyLib.MyStrings, LibText %>" />
```